# Xamarin.Android - No values returned when reading from xml file

Tags: c#, xml, xamarin

I know this is a very simple question-reading and parsing an xml file and has tons of solutions here already.Could you kindly assist me before shutting down this question?I'm new to C# and Xamarin as well,and have tried tons of solutions already but the result is always the same- nothing gets printed out to the console.Regardless of my implementation.The values are always null.Could you kindly check my code out,i have no idea why i'm not getting any data.

```
public List<SamplePoint> ReadFromFile()
    {
        pointList = new List<SamplePoint> ();


            xmldoc = new XmlDocument ();
            xmldoc.Load (fileLocation); //this is read from the sdcard of the device

XmlNodeList nodeList = xmldoc.DocumentElement.SelectNodes ("/SamplePoints/SamplePoint");

        foreach(XmlNode node in nodeList){


            endDate = node.SelectSingleNode ("EndDate").InnerText;

            startDate = node.SelectSingleNode ("startDate").InnerText;


return pointsList;
        }
```

Comment: The elements are in a namespace. You're not using that namespace. Will find a duplicate now. I'd strongly recommend using LINQ to XML instead of XmlDocument, btw.

Comment: @Jon Skeet thank you so much for your quick response.Could you kindly explain what you mean by the elements are in a namespace?I mean,i've worked with C# for a few weeks now and i know what a namespace is,but i don't know what you mean by 'the elements are in a namespace'.

Comment: It's not a C# aspect at all - it's XML. Your root element has `xmlns="..."` which means all unqualified elements are in that namespace. See the linked question.

Comment: @Jon Skeet i spent weeks literally trying to find out what i was doing wrong.Let me try that and i'll let you know if i succeed.Thanks a lot!

Comment: @Jon Skeet thank you for pointing me in the right direction.It worked perfectly.I just used the XmlNamespaceManager.

Comment: If you must - I still think you'd find it a lot easier to use LINQ to XML :)

Comment: I've seen a couple of LINQ examples around.Perhaps i'll look into that a little later.Thank you so much.You literally saved me days of debugging!Have you used the sqlite with xamarin.Android before as well?

Comment: Nope, not at all. But this is now way out of the scope of your question - this isn't a chat.